# Mimicking EventChannel broadcasts in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

Is there a way I can mimic a broadcast to an EventChannel in flutter? Something like `onEmit('some string', eventChannel)...`

Reason: we need to test input from a barcode scanner without running it on the device (Linea Infinea X) as some devs do not have an actual device

Here is the relevant code if it helps:

```
static const EventChannel eventChannel = const EventChannel('package:xpel_count_operations/linea');
...
...
// todo: onEmit('BARCODE', eventChannel);
eventChannel.receiveBroadcastStream().listen(_onEvent, onError: _onError);
```

Comment: Disregard question: Ill just override ```_onEvent()```